# Optimizing Oracle Update Select

Tags: oracle

I have a query as below

```
UPDATE CONVERTED T1 
   SET PARENTID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM 
                  CONVERTED T2 WHERE T2.ID < T1.ID 
                  AND T1.PREVOBJNUM = T2.OBID )
```

It takes several hours to run as their are 1 million records and it is having to perform a sub query for each row. Is there a way to optimize the query to run faster?

EDIT: here is the xplan

```
    Plan hash value: 3177327108

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT              |              |  1053K|    31M|   576M  (1)|802:56:03 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                       | CONVERTED    |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL           | CONVERTED    |  1053K|    31M| 84276   (1)| 00:07:03 |
|   3 |   SORT AGGREGATE              |              |     1 |    17 |            |          |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CONVERTED    |     1 |    17 |   547   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CONVERTED_PK |  9478 |       |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter("T2"."OBID"=:B1)
   5 - access("T2"."ID"<:B1)
```

and here is the table DLL

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table CONVERTED
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "AMS"."CONVERTED" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "L1" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L1_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L2" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L2_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L3" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L3_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L4" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L4_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L5" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L5_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L6" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L6_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L7" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L7_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L8" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L8_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L9" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L9_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L10" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L10_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L11" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L11_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L12" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L12_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L13" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L13_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L14" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L14_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L15" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "L15_DESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "OBID" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "OBDESC" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "MATTYPE" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "NUMOF" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "UOM" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "OBTYPE" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "PREVOBJNUM" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR), 
    "PARENTID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "POSITION" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "LEVEL_" NUMBER(10,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AMS_DATA" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index CONVERTED_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "AMS"."CONVERTED_PK" ON "AMS"."CONVERTED" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AMS_DATA" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table CONVERTED
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "AMS"."CONVERTED" ADD CONSTRAINT "CONVERTED_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "AMS_DATA"  ENABLE;
  alter table "AMS"."CONVERTED" modify ("ID" not null enable);
```

Here is the xplan with the index in place

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1448708152                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
| Id  | Operation                     | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT              |           |  1053K|    31M|  4296K (25)| 05:59:18 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|   1 |  UPDATE                       | CONVERTED |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL           | CONVERTED |  1053K|    31M| 84276   (1)| 00:07:03 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|   3 |   SORT AGGREGATE              |           |     1 |    17 |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|   4 |    FIRST ROW                  |           |     1 |    17 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)| INDEX1    |     1 |    17 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   5 - access("T2"."OBID"=:B1 AND "T2"."ID"<:B2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

 17 rows selected
```

Comment: Let's see the execution plan from DBMS_Xplan.Display please, and DDL for the tables and any indexes on CONVERTED

Comment: How many unique values of OBID are there?

Comment: There are 852,935 values of OBID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with an index on (OBID, ID), as it would avoid the table access on ID 4 of your explain plan.

The majority of the cost of the existing query comes from 1053K executions of the nested loop, where each loop execution costs 547. Of that 547, 22 is for using the index to access the table and 525 is for accessing the table. The table has to be accessed in order to find the rows for the specified OBID with an ID less than that for the row being updated. By including the ID in the index you allow the subquery to be executed without needing to access the table at all, which eliminates that cost of 525 per nested loop execution.

It would be interesting to look at the execution plan with that index in place. Probably the cost of accessing the index is now higher than the 22 quoted for the current index, but the overall cost of the nested loop will be much reduced.

Edit: Ah, the nested loop execution is now very efficient indeed. The optimiser does not just identify all of the candidate rows and then sort them to find the maximum ID, it finds the maximum ID by scanning the index directly. Nice.

Comment: The index seems to have fixed it. It nows takes a few seconds to do the update. Could you explain to me exactly why. I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to optimization

Comment: Add the new xplan to the question

Comment: Out of interest, what in the xplan pointed to you that an index on OBID, ID would improve performance?

Comment: It was more that the query indicated that an improvement might be possible with such an index. The plan helped to quantify the amount of performance improvement that might result, which would depend on all sorts of issues such as the clustering factor of the index on ID and the number of rows per block for the table.

Comment: Consider this: for the subquery in which you look up all the rows that have a given OBID and for which the ID is less than a certain number, how do you optimise it? If all you have is an index on ID then it's not going to perform well if ID is unique in the table.

Comment: So because ID and OBID are used in the where clause, it make sense in this case to index them?

Comment: Yes, and in particular because the select clause uses ID as well. If the select clause was "Max(someother_id)" then you'd definitely consider including that in the index (so it would be OBID, ID, SOMEOTHER_ID) *even if* the combination of OBID and ID was enough to uniquely identify a row in the table (which it is) because the value of SOMEOTHER_ID can be read without requiring that the tabnle be accessed. That's what is known as a "covering index", because the query can be satisfied by an index without the table being read.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot for your help on this. I think I understand when and were to index a little better now...

Comment: No probs: have a read through the docs as well ... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/toc.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a PL/SQL procedure that combines some advanced techniques like *BULK COLLECT*, *FORALL* statements and *PARALLEL* execution (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2.php will show you how to implement such solution).

Cyryl

Comment: PL/SQL methods are almost without exception slower than pure SQL methods. Every data read or write is carried out with SQL, and everything else is an overhead.